# How to display validation accuracy for multi-class image classification tasks in Keras?

Tags: python, keras, multiclass-classification, image-classification

I was implementing a multi-class image classification neural network in Keras (v2.4.3). I'd like to evaluate the performance of my model after being compiled and fitted.
[image]
After training, however, there is no information for the validation procedure. [image] So I checked the history keys and history, finding that there was no information about validation at all. [image]
[image]

How can I display the validation (categorical) accuracy for training my model? Any response will be appreciated!

Comment: Try `val_accuracy`

Comment: @George it showed KeyError: 'val_accuracy'.

Comment: I printed history.history and it contained values of 'loss', 'categorical_accuracy', and 'auc_3' in each epoch only. No validation info contained.

Answer (score 0):

So , running a small example

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import CategoricalAccuracy, AUC


X = np.random.rand(4, 4).astype(np.float32)

y = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
              [1, 1, 2, 2],
              [1, 2, 3, 3],
              [0,2,1,2]])

model = tf.keras.Sequential()

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(6, activation='relu', input_dim=4))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam',
              metrics = [CategoricalAccuracy(), AUC()])

history = model.fit(X, y, epochs=20, validation_split=0.2)
```

it shows :

```
Epoch 19/20
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 28ms/step - loss: 11.0286 - categorical_accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - auc_7: 0.9091 - val_loss: 7.1460 - val_categorical_accuracy: 1.0000 - val_auc_7: 0.6667
Epoch 20/20
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 49ms/step - loss: 11.0241 - categorical_accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - auc_7: 0.9091 - val_loss: 7.1411 - val_categorical_accuracy: 1.0000 - val_auc_7: 0.6667
```

If I remove the `validation_split=0.2` from fit, then it shows only training info:

```
Epoch 18/20
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 974us/step - loss: 9.0478 - categorical_accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - auc_8: 0.4821
Epoch 19/20
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 9.0495 - categorical_accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - auc_8: 0.4821
Epoch 20/20
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 9.0513 - categorical_accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - auc_8: 0.4821
```

So, I guess it has to do with something regard your validation iterator or/and validation steps.